# Vaadin flow multiple selection combobox

Tags: java, vaadin

I need to show multiple selection combobox in my grid header row to filter grid records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have integrated existing  [Polymer component](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/gatanasomultiselect-combo-box) into Vaadin flow:

```
@Tag("multiselect-combo-box")
@HtmlImport("src/views/common/multiselect-combo-box.html")
public class MultiSelectComboBox extends AbstractCallableComponent {

    private List<String> value;

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        JsonArray arr = Json.createArray();

        items.forEach(item -> {
            arr.set(arr.length(), item);
        });
        getElement().setPropertyJson("items", arr);
    }

    @ClientCallable
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 0) {
            value = Collections.emptyList();
        } else {
            value = Arrays.stream(s.split(","))
                    .map(String::trim)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        fireEvent(new ChangeEvent(this, false));
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Registration addChangeListener(ComponentEventListener<ChangeEvent> listener) {
        return addListener(ChangeEvent.class, listener);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ChangeEvent extends ComponentEvent<AbstractCallableComponent> {

    public ChangeEvent(AbstractCallableComponent source, boolean fromClient) {
        super(source, fromClient);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no official multi selection component for Vaadin Flow.

However, you can use the Java integration of the [`multiselect-combo-box`](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/gatanasomultiselect-combo-box) web component for [Vaadin Flow](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/multiselect-combo-box). You can see the live demo of the component [here](https://multiselect-combo-box-flow.herokuapp.com/).

To use the component, first add the dependency to you pom.xml file (check which is the latest version and modify it accordingly):

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.vaadin.gatanaso</groupId>
     <artifactId>multiselect-combo-box-flow</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <repository>
     <id>vaadin-addons</id>
     <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
```

Then instantiate the component and populate it with items:

```
MultiselectComboBox<String> multiselectComboBox = new MultiselectComboBox();
multiselectComboBox.setLabel("Select items");
multiselectComboBox.setItems("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4");
```

Optionally add a value change listener to get notified when a selection has changed:

```
multiselectComboBox.addValueChangeListener(e -> {
   // get the currently selected items
   Set<String> selectedItems = multiselectComboBox.getValue();
});
```

To use this component as a grid filter, I have modified the example from the Vaadin Grid [documentation](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/filtering), and it works as follows:

```
// setup grid with data provider
List<Person> personList = getItems();
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();

ListDataProvider<Person> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(personList);
grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);

// add a column
Grid.Column<Person> firstNameColumn = grid.addColumn(Person::getfirstName).setHeader("Name");

HeaderRow filterRow = grid.appendHeaderRow();

// define the multiselect combo box
MultiselectComboBox<String> multiselectComboBox = new MultiselectComboBox();

// set items to list of names
multiselectComboBox.setItems("Jack", "Nathan", "Andrew", "Peter", "Samuel");

// add a value change listener
multiselectComboBox.addValueChangeListener(e -> {
  // get the currently selected items
  Set<String> selectedItems = multiselectComboBox.getValue();
  String names = selectedItems.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));

  // filter the grid data provider
  if (selectedItems.size() > 0) {
    dataProvider.addFilter(person -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(person.getfirstName(), names));
  } else {
    dataProvider.clearFilters();
  }
});

// set the component as a filter
filterRow.getCell(firstNameColumn).setComponent(multiselectComboBox);
```

Hope this helps you achieve your goal!

BR,

Goran

Answer (score 0):

There has been an open [github issue about this](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/issues/88) for a looong time.

Someone already made a polymer component for it but has yet to integrate that into Vaadin Flow. It seems to me that this is finally taking off and I expect a multiselect combobox in Vaadin Flow soon-ish.

Comment: Thanks for link, I have integrated this polymer into Vaadin:

Answer (score 0):

Not available by default but the Vaadin team through [Vaadin ComponentFactory](https://vaadin.com/directory/search?author=Vaadin%20%20%20ComponentFactory) released [Multicombobox Component](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/multicombobox-component) which should be the best option for someone who wants/needs a long time supported component.

To add it to the `maven` project you need to add vaadin repository:

```
<repository>
   <id>vaadin-addons</id>
   <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
</repository>
```

and dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.vaadin.componentfactory</groupId>
   <artifactId>multi-combo-box-flow</artifactId>
   <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to the project `pom.xml` file.

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work with Vaadin 22 either. As far as I know there is no libarary for  Java multiselection box in Vaadin 22